# TikZ: draw line thickness less than 0.1 mm

Tags: tikz-pgf

In Ti*k*Z is it possible to draw lines thinner than 0.1 mm? `ultra thin` option gives line thickness 0.1 mm. I want to draw a pattern using line thickness 0.07 mm.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Sorry andrew. It was my first time and next time I will be careful to give MWE. I have got my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can specify the `line width`. Here is a zoomed in view of the output so that one can see the difference:

[image]

### Notes:

- As John Kormylo pointed out the `tikz-pgf` manual says about the "0 width" line:

  > **Line width**: The “thickness” of the line. A width of 0 is the thinnest width renderable on the device. On a high-resolution printer this may become invisible and should be avoided. A good choice is 0.4pt, which is the default.
- Obviously at some point the size difference won't be noticeable at all, especially in a print edition.

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5]
    \draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (0,-1) -- (2,-1) node [right] {\SI{0.25}{\milli\meter}};;
    \draw [line width=0.1mm,  blue] (0,-2) -- (2,-2) node [right] {\SI{0.10}{\milli\meter}};;
    \draw [line width=0.05mm, red ] (0,-3) -- (2,-3) node [right] {\SI{0.05}{\milli\meter}};
    \draw [line width=0.01mm, blue] (0,-4) -- (2,-4) node [right] {\SI{0.01}{\milli\meter}};
    \draw [line width=0mm,   black] (0,-5) -- (2,-5) node [right] {\SI{0.0}{\milli\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for using the `siunitx` package

Comment: @percusse : I am using the tikz-3dplot package which draw spheres with grid lines. There is not an option to remove the grid lines. I thought about making the line width=0 to remove the grid lines but I still got something. Is there a way to make the grid lines invisible with some pgf command? Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Is there anything to squeeze the option `draw=none`?

Comment: @percusse : No that I can see.  Thanks for your response. I am looking now into "pgfplots" .

Comment: You can have also `very thin`, `thin`, `thick`, `very thick` alternatives. That is `\draw[line width=very thick] (0,0) -- (4,0)`

Comment: @somenxavier no `line width=very thick` is a mistake and you get an error ! you can write `\draw[line width=0.4 pt]` or `\draw[very thick]`

Answer (score 9):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6.25,5.2)
  \multido{\rA = 0.1+-0.01, \rB = 0.1+0.5}{11}{
    \psline[linewidth = \rA mm](0,\rB)(5,\rB)
    \uput[0](5,\rB){\texttt{linewidth} = \SI[round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]{\rA}{\mm}}
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You specify the width of the line with the option `linewidth = <length>`.

P.S. As can be seen, the line width is too small to distinguish when using PSTricks, so that is not a good tool in this case. (I can't believe I'm saying that.)

Comment: +1 for (I can't believe I'm saying that.) :))