# Set line width independently of arrow size

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I would like to use lines with arrowheads in a Tikz drawing. The lines should have different thicknesses/widths, like so:

[image: Arrows with different line widths]

[Another answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204897/18853) pointed out the `line width` attribute to modify the width of a line in Tikz. I have tried this in a small example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,line width=1mm] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[-latex,line width=2mm] (0,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw[-latex,line width=3mm] (0,3) -- (5,3);
\draw[-latex,line width=4mm] (0,4.5) -- (5,4.5);
\draw[-latex,line width=5mm] (0,6) -- (5,6);
\draw[-latex,line width=6mm] (0,7.5) -- (5,7.5);
\draw[-latex,line width=7mm] (0,9) -- (5,9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, Tikz also scales up the arrowhead when using `line width`:

[image: Arrows with different line widths and different arrowhead sizes]

**How can I suppress this behaviour and force Tikz stick with a fixed arrowhead size across all line thicknesses?**

There does not seem to be an `arrowhead size` attribute, as far as I can see in the manual (?)

EDIT: For clarification, I am *not* looking for a way to set an arrowhead size on a per-line basis. I am looking for a way to set an *absolute* arrowhead size for a whole Tikz picture, which will then apply to all lines of a certain style, no matter which width they have (the width being set on a per-line basis!).

Comment: @c.p.: In the first question, something about the arrows still seems to depend on the line width, and especially for thicker lines, I seem to be getting only weird blobs (even when setting different `scale` values for lines of different thicknesses, which is what I would generally like to avoid for uniform arrowheads).

Comment: @c.p.: [One of the answers in the second link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8632/18853) sounds promising - regrettably, it only works for oversized arrows (compared to the line), not undersized ones. Note, however, that both questions aren't quite the same as here - I am specifically looking for reusing one particular arrow style several times, irrespective of line width. Individually dapting the arrow size for each line is a workaround at best in my question, while it is a fully valid solution for the linked questions that ask for actively resizing the arrowheads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the library `arrows.meta` and explicitly state the length and width or the arrows. You can do this for the entire picture, once - no need to do it for each individual case.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={LaTeX[width=10mm,length=10mm]},->]
  \draw[line width=1mm] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \draw[line width=2mm] (0,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
  \draw[line width=3mm] (0,3) -- (5,3);
  \draw[line width=4mm] (0,4.5) -- (5,4.5);
  \draw[line width=5mm] (0,6) -- (5,6);
  \draw[line width=6mm] (0,7.5) -- (5,7.5);
  \draw[line width=7mm] (0,9) -- (5,9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: explicit length and width for arrows]

Use `Triangle` rather than `LaTeX` for triangular tips:

[image: Triangular variation]

Comment: On its own, this seems to work. Unfortunately, it appears to get into a conflict with the Tikz-based edge definitions from [Tikz-uml](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en), which I am also trying to use in the same document. I will have to check whether I can replace Tikz-uml somehow. +1 for now, anyway.

Comment: I ended up dropping tikz-uml in favour of being able to use this solution and drawing my UML diagrams with [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Hmmm. I don't know much about that package as I don't think I've ever used it. I'm glad you found a workaround. An alternative would be to create some diagrams separately in something like `standalone` and then include them using `\includegraphics`. It is a shame about the conflict, though. If you wanted to follow up, I'd recommend asking a new question specifically about that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I downloaded the package to experiment and got errors. However, I get errors even if I just try to compile the example document I was testing which is provided by the package. So presumably I'm missing something essential in how to set this up ;).

Comment: It worked for me when just using the tikz-uml package. I will consider adding a separate question on that issue.

Comment: Interesting. Now, tikz-uml has completely stopped working for me, not only when `arrows.meta` is included. Maybe that was caused by my recent updating of Tikz, without which `arrows.meta` could not be loaded ... so much for using tikz-uml in any way.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Hmmm... You were presumably using TikZ 2.1 and now have TikZ 3 which introduced a number of changes.... I definitely think this is worth a question. Somebody might know an easy workaround.

Comment: That's great, thanks!  But what if I also want to have some lines in the same diagram *without* arrows?