# Add gaps to lines with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I am drawing some block diagrams with TikZ. Sometimes, I need to combine several blocks together to form one large group by adding a border around the corresponding blocks. However, there are some arrows which cross the border, as shown in this picture.

> [image: Block diagram without gaps]

The arrow "to ALC loop" and the arrow just below it looks ugly. What I would like to do is the following (note the small gaps around the arrows where they cross the thick border):

> [image]

How is that possible with TikZ? The arrows are just ordinary arrows drawn with the `\draw[->] (from) -- (to);` macro, and the thick border is also just an ordinary line.

Comment: See `double` option in section ["15.3.4 Graphic Parameters: Double Lines and Bordered Lines", p.169, pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=169) (v3.0.1a).

Comment: @Paul Gaborit - the disadvantage of the solution from your tip is that the shorten option can't be used as an input, because it is already applied in the problem solution: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/arrow-with-two-colors-with-tikz) -that is your solution here. Nevertheless your idea covers the case of overlapping arrow tip and external box border (in the picture in question).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using @AboAmmar MWE, `preaction` can be used in the simple case:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[> = latex]
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=5em] (rec) {};
\node [draw] (div) {$\div$};

\draw [preaction={draw, line width=3pt, white}][<->] (div) -- ++(5em,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: there is some problem nevertheless - arrow tip changes path bending dependently on the size of this arrow tip. So the idea is not good solution.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    outlined arrow/.style={
        preaction={{}-{},draw,line width=3pt,yellow}
    }
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = latex]
\node [draw,thick,minimum size=5em] (rec) {};
\node [draw] (div) {$\div$};

\draw [outlined arrow][<->] (div) -- ++(5em,0);
\draw [outlined arrow][<->,shorten <=2pt] (div) .. controls +(-90:15mm) and +(180:15mm) .. ++(5em,-5em);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT 2: In the above case black arrow bent line goes not in the middle of yellow line - dependently on the arrow size. I found that @cfr response ([arrow tip size independent on the line width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261742/set-line-width-independently-of-arrow-size)) can be useful a bit here. The code below works only when the arrow tip setup `my arrow` is passed through optional argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    outlined arrow/.style={preaction={double=yellow,double distance=2pt,draw=red}},
    my arrow/.style={>={LaTeX[length=2mm]}},
    yscale=0.6
]
\node [draw,thick,minimum size=5em] (rec) {};
\node [draw] (div) {$\div$};

\draw [outlined arrow][<->,my arrow] (div) -- ++(5em,0);
\draw [outlined arrow][<->,shorten <=2pt,my arrow]
      (div) .. controls +(-90:15mm) and +(180:15mm) .. ++(5em,-5em);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I considered also the use of @Qrrbrbirlbel solution ([save a path and call it for stroking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/stroke-a-predefined-path)), but `shorten` option didn't work. Also @Paul Gaborit solution ([surrounded arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/arrow-with-two-colors-with-tikz)) excludes `shorten` option (?).

Comment: this is perfect!

Answer (score 10):

These gaps at line crossings can be achieved with a thick white-colored line drawn the same way as your crossing line. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[> = latex]
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=5em] (rec) {};
\node [draw] (div) {$\div$};

\draw [<->, line width=3pt, white](div) -- ++(5em,0);
\draw [<->] (div) -- ++(5em,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you. I already had that idea too, but it has the disadvantage that the corresponding arrows have to be drawn twice. I wonder whether there is an 'automatic' way?