# I want to color a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Im very new to making latex so all the tutorials I have found about my question were too hard to understand or didn't do exactly what I wanted.

I already have the graph I want without the coloring:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
     \draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1.71:1.71,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3});

      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: (written without compiling) `\fill [green] (-2,0) plot [domain=0:1.26] (\x,\x^3) |- cycle;`

Comment: Oh i didnt know it was that  easy! It looks good, but because of the scale=0.4, the green area isnt correctly under the graph. How to i re-scale the green area?

Comment: I figured it out! i just added it in the square brackets: `\fill [green, scale=0.4] (-2,2) plot [domain=0:0.5] (\x,\x^3) |- cycle;`

Comment: But how do I color even farther out to the right like I drew on the paper? And how to color the other four areas?

Comment: Either you specify coordinates carefully (e.g. `1.26` in my code in cubic root of `2`) or use `\clip`

Comment: Where should i specify 1.26 in your code? What does this part `(-2,2)` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, without slightly line, because the filling is made differently (code modified from AndréC answer):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
    \clip[postaction={fill=green!50}] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[scale=0.4,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue!20] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3}) |-(0,0);
    \fill[scale=0.4,domain=0:-5,smooth,variable=\x,blue!20] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3}) |-(0,0);
    \draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1.71:1.71,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3});
\end{scope}

\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Code edited with marmot's useful suggestion: using `postaction` to reduce redundant code.)

[image]

Comment: @marmot Thanks, I have edited with your great advice.

Answer (score 3):

A tricky way:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!20] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[green!50] (0,0)--({-1.71*0.4},{0.4*(-1.71^3)})--(2,-2)--(2,0)--cycle;
\fill[green!50] (0,0)--({1.71*0.4},{0.4*(1.71^3)})--(-2,2)--(-2,0)--cycle;
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1.71:1.71,smooth,variable=\x,black,fill=green!50] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit:

A tricky way needs to be continued by a tricky addition. I added a `line width=0mm` line (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204896/tikz-draw-line-thickness-less-than-0-1-mm)):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!20] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[green!50] (0,0)--({-1.71*0.4},{0.4*(-1.71^3)})--(2,-2)--(2,0)--cycle;
\fill[green!50] (0,0)--({1.71*0.4},{0.4*(1.71^3)})--(-2,2)--(-2,0)--cycle;
\draw[line width=0mm,green!50] ({1.71*0.4},{0.4*(1.71^3)})--({-1.71*0.4},{0.4*(-1.71^3)}); % <===================
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1.71:1.71,smooth,variable=\x,black,fill=green!50] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The very thin line has gone I think.

[image]

Comment: We see a line that joins the two ends of the curve.

Comment: That looks exactly like i want it! But is there any way to get around that slightly visible dark-green line that goes from (1.71*0.4, 0.4*(1.71^3)) to (-1.71*0.4,0.4*(-1.71^3))?

Comment: @Hans See my answer, I have removed the slight line with a different filling technique.

Comment: @Hans I have edited my answer. (I'm sorry for being late).

Comment: By the way, as my solution is not standard, it doesn't deserve a tick. Accept quark67's answer instead.

Comment: @Hans You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

With `pgfplots`, this is easy to do.

Here is a pure `tikz` DIY **without** a single piece of pgfplots!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!20] (-2,-2)rectangle(2,2);
\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=1]   
\fill[scale=0.4,domain=0:1.71,smooth,variable=\x,green] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3})coordinate(a)|-(0,0)node[midway](m){};
\fill[green](a)--(2,2)|-(m.west);
\fill[scale=0.4,domain=0:-1.71,smooth,variable=\x,green] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3})coordinate(b)|-(0,0)node[midway](n){};
\fill[green](b)--(-2,-2)|-(n.east);
\end{scope}
\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1.71:1.71,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{(\x)^3});
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is a slight vertical line in your screenshot (at x=-1.71) because you fill this lower left domain with 2 areas (there is also a slight vertical line at x=+1.71 in the upper right domain, but not visible in your screenshot).

Comment: You have a much better view than I do. I have just created a `transparency group`, normally this little net should have disappeared.