# Drawing a random function to show the definition of the limit

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good morning, [image]

Im trying to reproduce the attached figure in ordre to clarify the definition of the limit of a function. Can you help me please to finish the tikz code that I already started.

My problem is the random function in the picture as well as the arrows on both x et y axis.

This is my code :

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-3,-3) grid (6,4);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-3)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[dashed,color=blue] (2,0) node[below] {$$} -- (2,0.69) -- (0,0.69)
    node[left] {};
    \draw[dashed,] (2.5,0) node[below] {$x_0$} -- (2.5,0.916) -- (0,0.916)
    node[left] {$l$};
    \draw[dashed,color=blue] (3,0) node[below] {$$} -- (3,1.09) -- (0,1.09)
    node[left] {};
    \draw[thick,red,domain=0.5:5.5,samples=200] (2,3) node[anchor=north west] {} plot (\x,{ln(\x)});
    %\node[fill=green, text=red, circle, draw=black] {With node}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: You can use a [smooth curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz) based on some points, avoiding to define a mathematical function.

Comment: @Karlo thank you very much for the comment. Do you have any idea how to make the intervals on the x-axis ??

Comment: Does plotting lines with [different line widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204896/tikz-draw-line-thickness-less-than-0-1-mm) help you?

Comment: @Karlo I will try, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the provided picture the bounds are a little off, so I changed that. A comment on style, your choice of `ultra thick` for lines is a little weird, also if your prefer the log function, you can replace `ln(\x)` in `% f(x) (sigmoid)` however you would have to recompute the bounds, in that regard a more elegant solution is to pass the values of the `%bounds` nodes to `% Lower %Upper %Arrows`, take it as homework :).
[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
        % grid and Axis
        \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-3 , -3) grid (5 , 4);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-3 , 0) -- (5 , 0) node[right]{$x$}; 
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0 , -3) -- (0, 4) node[above]{$y$}; 
    % Bounds and function value
    \draw[dashed,color=blue] (3.5, 0) node[below right]
            {$\scriptstyle x_0+\delta$} -- (3.5 , 3.1) -- (0 , 3.1)
            node[left] {$\scriptstyle l+\varepsilon$}; %Upper
    \draw[dashed,] (3  , 0) node[below = 1.5 mm] 
            {$\scriptstyle x_0$} -- (3 , 2.55) -- (0 , 2.55)
            node[left] {$\scriptstyle l$}; % l
    \draw[dashed,color=blue] (2.5 ,  0) node[below left]
            {$\scriptstyle x_0-\delta$} -- (2.5 , 2.0) -- (0 , 2.0)
            node[left] {$\scriptstyle l-\varepsilon$}; % Lower
    \draw[ultra thick,red,domain=-1.8 : 2.25 , samples = 20] {} 
            plot ((\x + 2 , {exp(\x + 1.5)/(2 +  exp(\x)}); % f(x)
    % Annotations
    \draw [|-|, ultra thick, green ] (2.5 , 0) -- (3.0 , 0) 
        node[midway, below = 2.50mm]{$\scriptstyle \delta$}; 
    \draw [<-> , thin , blue] (0.25 , 2.55) -- (0.25 , 3.1)
        node[midway, right] {$\scriptstyle \varepsilon$}; % Upper Arrow
    \draw [<-> , thin , blue] (0.25 , 2) -- (0.25 , 2.55)
            node[midway, right] {$\scriptstyle \varepsilon$}; % Lower Arrow     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Thank you for taking the time to answer me, this help me a lot.

Comment: Sure, <3 if you ever find out how to pass the boundspost it